# facebook-android-sdk: Force reauthentication using the sdk 3.0.1

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-authentication, facebook-authorization

Is there a way to trigger a reauthentication dialog using the `facebook-android-sdk` 3.0.1? It is possible using the JavaScript SDK (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/reauthentication/), but I haven't found anything for the Android SDK.

The dialog should be triggered when the user wants to enter the "Edit my profile" section of the app.

Comment: Hey do did you find a solution to this problem ?

Comment: Unfortunately not :( This issue is still open :(

Comment: I think it's possible to try using WebView in android and then access JS sdk.. What do you think ?

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null){
            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
            session = null;
            Log.i(TAG, "cleared session");
            Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, sessionCallback);
        }
```

Comment: With this code the session will be closed even if the user decides to cancel the re-authentication dialog? Is there any way to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Yes, but you can call this code only in the cases when you need this behavior. Besides the last line of code cause a new dialog to be shown, so remove it if you don't want it.

Comment: So the Facebook session is still open if the re-authentication dialog is shown and the user cancels it?! I don't think so but this is a requirement :(

Comment: In fact you will have a session with `SessionState` = CREATED. If the user cancel the dialog the session will not transits to the OPENED state.